# packet loss in ping

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, ping

I'm new to linux. Currently I have two ubuntu VMs on a Windows 8 host.
I created two virtual networks for both VMs as below:
1-NAT : to use the windows 8 internet 
Two internal connections to connect to each other for running hadoop.
Everything is normal, they can ping each other and I can browse websites.
But when I ping a Website I browsed all of them have more than 70% packet loss.
So I looked at `/etc/interfaces` and I only see these two lines:

`auto lo`
`iface lo inet loopback`

When I execute `ifconfig` I have `eth0`,`eht1` and `lo`.
Do I have to change the interfaces? How can I prevent the package loss?
I am running apache nutch and I have an error on it, I know it is because of this that it can not connect to the internet to crawl a website.

Comment: ping the default gateway and let it go for some time see if you're loosing packets there

Comment: @meccooll no i don't have any packets loss there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem .

1- shut down both VMs and recreate virtual network adapter . first for internet(NAT) second for internal network .

2- turn on VMs . delete both connection in network manager .

3-open /etc/network/interfaces

4-add these lines :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

4-restart network.
now i can browse in browser and ping without any packet loss .

Comment: To anyone who's visiting this: This did not work for me and will probably not work for you. Personally, I had to add DNS nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf (add lines: "nameserver 8.8.8.8" and "nameserver 8.8.4.4" and then set a proxy (because I'm on a corporate network). Then I had to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain the situation better?

Here is what I understand from your write-up.

- You have a Windows machine.
- You have installed some virtualization software on your Windows machine.
- You have created two "identical" virtual machines, each running some version of Ubuntu.
- Within each VM you have 3 interfaces: lo0 (obviously), eth0 and eth1.
- One of the ethX interfaces on each VM connects to the outside world, either through NAT or bridging or whatever.
- The other ethX interface on each VM connects to the other VM.

If all that understanding is correct, could you kindly do the following:

- Shutdown the VM-s. Ping your chosen site from Windows. Do you see a packet loss?
- Bring up one VM. Ping your chosen site from Windows. Do you see a packet loss?
- With the previous VM up-n-running, log into that VM and ping your chosen site from within the VM. Do you see a packet loss?
- Bring up the second VM. So, now you have both the VM-s up-n-running. Ping your chosen site from Windows. Do you see a packet loss?
- With both the VM-s up-n-running, log into VM-1 and ping your chosen site from within the VM. Do you see a packet loss?
- With both the VM-s up-n-running, log into VM-2 and ping your chosen site from within the VM. Do you see a packet loss?

Please note that I don't have an answer at this point in time and I am not quite likely to have an answer, but, if you fill in all that info, someone here will be able to help. I feel, that as stated currently, your question may be very vague and hence the request for more info.

Comment: all of your understanding are correct . i do what you said and in all of the situation, in windows i don't have any packet loss and in ubuntus i have packet loss.

Comment: could you switch from nat to bridged and try the whole experiment again? please?

also, am I correct in understanding that there are packet losses when pinging the 1st hop router?

Comment: no this is not correct . The amazing part's here . When i switch to bridged mode i can ping without any packets loss. but i can not brows any page in the browser .

Comment: so, you have significant packet loss in nat mode but no packet loss in bridged mode, as I was expecting. now ... #1: what is not correct? #2: a diagram of your setup would have been really helpful. that said, output of "ifconfig" and "netstat -nr" for each vm and for the host would also be very helpful. finally, it would be helpful if you provide info on what ip addresses you are trying to ping.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not packet loss to the first hope (your router) that means that it's out of your PCs hands and the problem is somewhere up stream from your router. Not much you can do on a PC to effect how the packet will be handled after your router

Comment: What IP are you trying to ping? And what kind of internet connection are you on? From ubuntu do `tracepath IP` that should give you a list of your hops then ping each ip starting from 1 until you start seeing packet loss